# super.clone() Queries?

Tags: java

Kindly clarify me for the following questions.

1. Does `super.clone()` perform Deep copying or shallow copying?
2. In the below example, why don't we need class `CompositeObjCloneMe` as cloneable? Does `cObj` won't be cloned while trying to clone `CloneMe` object?
   Note: Even making `CompositeObjCloneMe` as cloneable doesn't have any impact on output.
3. Why the output is behaving like shallow copying (Not deep coppying) since program is setting primitive value(`setCObjValue = 100`) of a class? (where primitive fields are deeply copied)
4. Is it immutable Objects && primitives are inherently deeply copied?

   ```
   class CloneMe implements Cloneable {
       private CompositeObjCloneMe cObj;

       public CloneMe() {
           cObj = new CompositeObjCloneMe();
         }

       public void setCObjValue(int myOwnDt) {
           this.cObj.setObj(myOwnDt);
       }
       public int getCObjValue() {
           return this.cObj.getObj();
       }
       //Clone
       public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
       return super.clone();
       }
   }

   class CompositeObjCloneMe {//implements Cloneable{
       private int value = 20;
       public void setObj(int i){
           value = i;
       }
       public int getObj(){
           return value;
       }
   //  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
   //      return super.clone();
   //  }
   }


   public class CloneTest {
       public static void main(String arg[]) {
           CloneMe realObj = new CloneMe();
           try {
               CloneMe cloneObj = (CloneMe) realObj.clone();
               realObj.setCObjValue(100);
               System.out.println(realObj.getCObjValue()  + "   " + cloneObj.getCObjValue());
           } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
               System.out.println("Cloneable should be implemented. " + cnse);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

OUTPUT:   100   100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) to the rescue:

> [...] Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not
>   a "deep copy" operation.

2) Because clone doesn't call clone recursively. It's a shallow clone. It just creates a new object with the same references as the original one, and copies of primitive fields.

3) I don't understand what you mean. Primitive are not deeply copied. They don't reference anything, so there's nothing deep to copy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. point 2 clears all my doubts. I confused recursive operation like serialization.

Comment: Is it possible to perform deep copying using super.clone()?

Comment: No. You'll have to call it, and then explicitely clone all the referenced objects yourself, recursively (which is not always possible). A copy constructor is generally preferred over clone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think i can go ahead with copy constructor whenever i need deep copying.

Answer (score 1):

The first and second question have already been answered by JB Nizet.

For your third question, both your `realObj` and the `cloneObj` refer to the same `CompositeObjCloneMe` instance. When you clone your real object, the clone object's `CompositeObjCloneMe` field `cObj` will be the same instance as in `realObj`. Hence altering the `cObj` of `realObj` by calling `realObj.setCObjValue(100);` will affect `cloneObj` as well.

So the output is exactly what was expected.

Note: you can easily verify this by using a debugger and looking at the field of `realObj` and `cloneObj`

If you want to have a deep clone, you should call super.clone and make a clone of the non-primitive fields as well. E.g.

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
  CloneMe clone = (CloneMe)super.clone();
  clone.cObj = ...;//make a clone, a new instance, ...
  return clone;
}
```

It is important to call `super.clone` to create the object you will return and not simply call `CloneMe clone = new CloneMe();`. Otherwise if a subclass wants to implement clone as well, it would have to duplicate all the logic in your class.

Some extra documentation: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29), [Codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0128.shtml)

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Is it possible to perform deep copying using super.clone()?